# Problem in attaching file through apex:inputFile

Tags: visualforce, attachment

I have apex:inputFile on my page. It is rendered on some condition. When it is initially rendered and i upload file then i gets the attachment on my controller. But when it is not rendered initially and I change some condition on which it is rendered then i try to attach file, I didn't get attachment on my controller.

```
<apex:actionRegion >
    <apex:actionFunction name="setTest" action="{!setUpload}" reRender="eval,errMsg">
        <apex:param name="meParam" value="" assignTo="{!showUpload}" />
    </apex:actionFunction> 
</apex:actionRegion>

<apex:pageBlockSection id="eval"> 
        <apex:actionRegion >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Test" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.Test__c}" onChange="setTest(this.value);"/>

    </apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:actionRegion >
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!attach.Id == null && con.Test__c == 'Yes'}"> 
        <apex:inputFile value="{!attach.Body}" fileName="{!attach.Name}" contentType="{!attach.contentType}" style="width:35%;"/>
        <apex:commandLink value="Upload" action="{!uploadDocument}" immediate="true">
        </apex:commandLink>

    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:actionRegion>
<apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code in order we better understand ?

Comment: @SF_user I have attached code.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the rendered attribute to hide VF components, they don't get hooked up to the controller.

The best workaround is to use css styles instead of the rendered attriubute to hide/unhide it. That way, SF connects the fields up, even when the component is not being displayed on the screen.

i.e.

Remove the rendered attribute from the apex:pageBlockSectionItem, then modify the apex:inputFile like this:

```
<apex:inputFile value="{!attach.Body}" fileName="{!attach.Name}" contentType="{!attach.contentType}" style="width:35%; display: {!IF(attach.Id == null && con.Test__c == 'Yes', 'inline-block', 'none');"/>
```